# How to get gateway information for both interface as gateway information shows as 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux, networking, router, routing, gateway

I have two interfaces with me as eth0 and wwan0.
My both the interfaces have internet connectivity. But in my use case, I can plug and unplug any interface from my system.
Ideally as soon I plug it again, if I add the gateway to route, my internet connection will resume.

The problem here is that I always get information about default gateway only.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
8.8.8.8         192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.177.88.96    *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 wwan0
59.144.127.17   192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Here, I have the gateway for eth0 but gateway information for wwan0 is 0.0.0.0.

**EDIT1:**

**Setup:** 
I am having two interfaces as eth0 and wwan0. Both are having internet connectivity.

**Problem:** Out of these two interfaces, I can ping only via one interface. I can ping only through the interface which is by default. 
Now to ping through another interface, I try to add the gateway to route and it works fine with this command

```
route add default gw " + GW + wwan0/eth0 --> Depeneds on which one is not pinging
```

In my route table for the interface which is not pinging, gateway information is 0.0.0.0. I am getting gateway information to add manually from dhcp.lease file but I need gateway information on fly so that via some script, I can achieve the same.

**Kernel IP routing table**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
8.8.8.8         192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.177.88.96    *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 wwan0
59.144.127.17   192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.42.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

**ip route**

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
10.177.88.96/28 dev wwan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.177.88.104
59.144.127.17 via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
192.168.0.0/22 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.166
192.168.2.1 dev eth0  scope link
192.168.42.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.1
```

Ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:B3:D5:9A:EF:FC
          inet addr:192.168.2.166  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::72b3:d5ff:fe9a:effc%1995519696/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1866379 (1.7 MiB)  TX bytes:27888 (27.2 KiB)

wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1E:10:1F:00:00
          inet addr:10.177.88.104  Bcast:10.177.88.111  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:10ff:fe1f:0%1995519696/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6682 (6.5 KiB)  TX bytes:16247 (15.8 KiB)
```

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: How is `getting information about default gateway only` a problem. Moreover your question is unclear. Please provide an instance of what you want and what you are getting and also what you have tried ?

Comment: What routing table do you see when _only_ wwan0 is active? (Since it's Linux, could you show output of `ip route` instead?)

Comment: Updated Original question with Ip route and clear problem

Comment: That's the usual multi homed system: requires policy routing to have both default routes working at the same time. Still only one will show on the "main" table, alternate default routes are on additional tables triggered by rules. See this a bit outdated document to get the idea: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html. usually also requires iptables, to do some choice (round robin...) and help the routing with marks on packets